# How to get a Request from Http's Response in Angular 2?

Tags: http, angular

In Angular 1 it was just a matter of accessing a `config` field in a response object. How to do the same thing in Angular 2? (I was looking at `Response` typings but I didn't notice anything which could be used for this purpose.)

I hope I won't have to manually save every request and somehow pair it with a response (by `url`? not sure if it is even filled in a `Response`).

Comment: What do you mean with "get a Request"? You normally use get or post with a request and get a response.. Do you mean you want to get the original request from the response?

Comment: @Patrick Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I need a `Request` object (the configuration for the `Http`) from a `Response` object (I need to resend that original `Request` with other auth header).